# GWT Hosted Mode Script Windows

Tags: bash, gwt, batch-file

The company I work for uses Mac computers exclusively.  While I like my Mac, it is only a 13" laptop so I decided to setup my environment on my Windows pc as I have two 24" monitors to work from.  I want to be able to use devMode so I can update the UI without having to recompile everything. I was wondering if there is an easy way to convert a bash shell script into a windows batch file. Im not experienced at all in creating batch files so any help would be greatly appreciated

edit: I used Cygwin and I get the error:

```
$ ./devMode_osx.sh
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5006
Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode
```

Here's the file

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Startup script for hosted mode.
# You have to add MAVEN_REPO to your variables; for example:
#
# export MAVEN_REPO="/Users/james/.m2/repository"
#
MAVEN_REPO="C:/Users/James/.m2/repository"
JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_38"
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

APPDIR=`dirname $0`;

BASE_JAVA_SRC="$APPDIR/../src/main/java"
BASE_JAVA_CLASSES="$APPDIR/../target/classes"
BASE_RESOURCES="$APPDIR/../src/main/webapp/"
DOMAIN_JAVA_SRC="$APPDIR/../../sample-domain/src/main/java"
DOMAIN_JAVA_CLASSES="$APPDIR/../../sample-domain/target/classes"
DOMAIN_JAVA_RESOURCES="$APPDIR/../../sample-domain/src/main/resources"

GWT_USER="$MAVEN_REPO/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.3.0/gwt-user-2.3.0.jar"
GWT_DEV="$MAVEN_REPO/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.3.0/gwt-dev-2.3.0.jar"
JAVAX_VALIDATION="$MAVEN_REPO/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-        1.0.0.GA.jar"
JAVAX_VALIDATION_SRC="$MAVEN_REPO/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar"

JVMARGS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=5006,server=y,suspend=n"

#MP: run HostedMode with 'war' parameter set, as below, to specify, where the gwt output files are written to
#-war $BASE_RESOURCES

java $JVMARGS -XX:PermSize=256m -Xmx900M -Xms900M -cp "$BASE_JAVA_SRC:$BASE_JAVA_CLASSES:$BASE_RESOURCES:$GWT_USER:$GWT_DEV:$JAVAX_VALIDATION:$JA    VAX_VALIDATION_SRC:$DOMAIN_JAVA_SRC:$DOMAIN_JAVA_CLASSES:$DOMAIN_JAVA_RESOURCES" \
com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode \
-startupUrl Sample.html com.ngcompliance.web.gwt.Sample\
-noserver -port 9999 -war $BASE_RESOURCES
```

Comment: You could install `cygwin` on your windows or better: install `linux` on your PC!

Comment: I added an edit, I tried cygwin and I get an error.

Comment: So, if your compagny use Mac OsX, why did you try to share with Windows? Linux is a lot more `X` friendly! Install Linux!

Comment: I want to, I'm pretty much re-styling the entire application/dashboards and I dont have Photoshop for OS X and I dont think you can run Photoshop on Linux AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches:

1. Use Cygwin (www.cygwin.com) to run a Bash shell script under Windows.
2. Take a basic batch programming tutorial.

   Pay attention to the part of setting and accessing variables.

   And then try to modify your bash script

   ---

   **Hint 1** setting variables

   instead of

   ```
   MAVEN_REPO="C:/Users/James/.m2/repository"
   ```

   use

   ```
   SET MAVEN_REPO="C:/Users/James/.m2/repository"
   ```

   ---

   **Hint 2** using variables

   instead of

   ```
   BASE_JAVA_SRC="$APPDIR/../src/main/java"
   ```

   use

   ```
   SET BASE_JAVA_SRC="%APPDIR%/../src/main/java"
   ```

   ---

   **Hint 3** review use of external commands and SO idiosyncrasies

   instead of

   ```
   APPDIR=`dirname $0`;
   ```

   use

   ```
   SET APPDIR=%~dp0
   ```

Comment: I added an edit, I tried cygwin and I get an error. I'm going to try #2 and see how it goes! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you just not use eclipse, gpe plugin and maven plugin.

1. Gpe - https://developers.google.com/eclipse/
2. Gwt gpe faq -https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq
3. Gwt with maven - htpp://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven